# limit $x \cdot \sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})$ as $x\rightarrow \infty $

Tags: limits

I want to calculate limit $x \cdot \sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})$ as $x \rightarrow \infty $ without L'Hôpital's rule.
I found this task on the Internet. The answer given by the author is $2$.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x \cdot \sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}) = \\
= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x \cdot \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}}\cdot(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}) =  (*)\\
$$
at this point I took care of a sine interior
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2} = \\ 
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}) \cdot(\sqrt{x^2+3} + \sqrt{x^2+2})}{(\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2})} = \\ 
= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2})} = \left[\frac{1}{\infty}\right] = 0 \\ 
 $$
and whole sin function
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}} = \left[\frac{\sin(y\rightarrow0)}{y\rightarrow0}\right] = 1 $$
finally
$$(*) =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}}\cdot  \frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2})} = \\ = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2})}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}}\cdot  \frac{x}{x \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)} = \frac{1}{2}  $$

Unfortunately $\frac{1}{2} \neq 2$ so who is wrong? (and if I'm wrong, then why?)

Comment: You can address this question ? where is this ? in which book  ? (I think your work is correct )

Comment: The answer is $\frac{1}{2}$. Next time you can check the result by your self using wolfram:http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: I think that it is originally from [link](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~pawelst/analiza/Analiza_Matematyczna_1/Notatki_itp./Archiwum_files/JawnaPula2012-13-ver01a.pdf). This is a set of tasks for first year undergraduate students in mathematics from the University of Warsaw in Poland.

Comment: One small error, a typo since what follows is ok: all following sin in (*) should be in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did nothing wrong, so you are correct. Good job! The answer is $\frac 12$.

Comment: It should be a comment !

Answer (score 1):

It would be absurd not to agree with everything said, but this is how I would approach this task:

$\begin{aligned}\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(x\cdot\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)\right)&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac3{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac2{x^2}}\right)\right)}{\frac1x}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\frac1{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac2{x^2}}}\right)}{\frac1{x}}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac3{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac2{x^2}}\right)}\right)}{\frac1{x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac3{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac2{x^2}}\right)}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac2{x^2}}}\\&=\frac12\end{aligned}$
Which is essentially the same thing you did.

Comment: Thank you very much ...$\infty$.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you don't have to thank me because I really enjoy communicating with people of the same interests. Therefore I consider myself a happy person.